# Should I use div.class or .class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have recently observed the following change more and more often, people write `div.class` or `div#id` instead of just `.class` or `#id`.

What is the best way to target your classes in CSS  And why?

If I remember correctly, `div.class` has the same result as `.class`.?

Comment: Rules set under `.class` can be used for a `span` also whereas `div.class` would apply only when the `div` tag has that class. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2b1xso8/) is a sample. The other part on which is better depends on how you want to re-use your classes. If the same rules will apply for multiple types of tags, define without the tag name.

Comment: `div.class` only works the same as `.class` if all your `.class`es are `<div>`s.

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity understanding it will save you a lot of time in the future:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`div.class` will affect only to `div` elements, and is more specific than just using `.class`. So, if you write both, `div.class` and just `.class` in a div, the first one will win in preference.

But I think that is more elegant don't using it, if you don't have a good reason for that (you may want to apply something just to `div` elements with this class and not to any other).

Comment: Aaaah, yes, of course! Thanks for clarifying. Why didn't I think of that myself.

Answer (score 4):

What the best way is depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to make sure that a block style can't be accidentally applied to an inline element? Or do you have complex CSS and performance is becoming an issue?

If you use `div.class`, then the style will only be applied to `div` with that class. `<span class="class">` won't be affected. That means you can also define `span.class` to do something special for `span` or you can move common styles to a generic `.class` definition.

If you care about performance, here are a couple of links for you:

- http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS
- http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

(google for `css performance`)

Answer (score 2):

`.class` will effect all the element we gave class name as class. If you use `div.class`, then the style will only be applied to div with that class. Other elements won't be affected. following fiddle explains more.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtcyvju2/

Answer (score 0):

`.class` can be used for both **div class** and **span** also & div.class can be used when tag has that specific class